# Creating custom rules

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, catalog-rules

I am trying to implement the following: [image]

The idea is to be able to filter products by the conditions which allow only product attributes. (I do not want the additional columns in the grid instead). When I click "All" or "TRUE" or green "+" nothing happens. I know this feature involves a lot of deep Magento knowledge which I don't yet posses. For now I am trying to make the code work the dirty way (I am amending core files) for testing purposes. Ideally I need to have an observer or the layout file.
The core file I amend to implement the feature is called `Tabs.php` and is located under `app/code/Core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Category` directory. 
The particular function is called `_prepareLayout()` I am trying to inject the created form to the `Category Products` tab which is represented by the class extending the grid. Since I am adding a new form to the tab alongside the original grid I concluded to amend the `Tabs.php` file instead of the `Grid.php` one. Here is the content:

```
    $model = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->getCollection()->getFirstItem();
    $renderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton('adminhtml/widget_form_renderer_fieldset');
    $text = 'Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions (leave blank for all items)';
    $config = array('legend' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__($text));
    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('actions_fieldset', $config)->setRenderer($renderer);
    $fieldset->addField('actions', 'text', array(
        'name' => 'actions',
        'label' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply To'),
        'title' => Mage::helper('salesrule')->__('Apply To'),
        'required' => true,
    ))->setRule($model)->setRenderer(Mage::getBlockSingleton('rule/actions'));
    $form->setValues($model->getData());
    $this->addTab('products', array(
        'label'     => Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Category Products'),
        'content'   => $form->toHtml() . $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'adminhtml/catalog_category_tab_product',
            'category.product.grid'
        )->toHtml(),
    ));
```

The original "Shopping Cart Price Rules" is implemented in (there are tons of files really, but the main one is probably in) the `Actions.php` file located under `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Promo/Quote/Edit/Tab` directory. The function is called `_prepareForm()`.

Can you help me by giving a hint on how can I implement that rule block please? Huge thank you in advance!

Comment: This is not a small task. Will require a lot of code blocks and understanding of how the rules system works. At this point i would be so bold as to refer you to my extension that already does this planned functionality, and if i can say so myself, does it very well. :) http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-dynamic-category-products.html